# How to remove spikes from data with Python using signal.find_peaks

Tags: statistics, data-cleaning, preprocessing

I need to make a regression model to estimate data values in future. Train set contains occasional spikes that make my model less accurate, thus I'm trying to locate and remove them. I've used `scipy.find_peaks` and it works great, but I don't quite understand how to adjust this method arguments in order to capture only outstanding spikes - now it captures even slightest of them.

Here I'd like to replace spikes 1,2 and maybe 3 with median value from some local area around those spikes.
[image]

Here is whole code with sample data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1499.92837649,1498.74695136,1501.65412106,1852.75606625,1529.10227068,1527.2338009,1511.42044108,1508.18740648,1505.78652903,1515.93546365,1511.83021892,1504.59584562,1508.78471494,1500.78264115,1405.06811723,1397.95364197,1441.55203344,1482.71423213,1478.62308578,1497.64108386,1501.68473585,1506.23520923,1496.6881723,1498.70582285,1496.92464156,1491.36344958,1497.02274755,1493.25840383,1467.99193355,1488.16412732,1564.90609222,4324.09218032,1504.01615122,1516.59231739,1502.65908262,1491.34087737,1495.48497145,1482.18263694,1486.75207092,1488.28305886,1503.25046412,1488.96239452,1481.77735161,1486.36756273,1487.62106583,1401.90394972,1312.80471197,1245.19721745,1243.21820291,1241.83373451,1252.64588912,1323.309521,1373.16110944,1382.73759737,1406.10184314,1386.36355816,1363.1847865,1372.95915991,1316.68933536,1198.69830381,1377.63603792,1352.5725527,1164.1890967,1415.80938398,1404.66987602,1385.51846367,1379.27067776,1378.43735237,1382.84139049,1384.81287032,1384.59375778,1385.73733668,1386.34247221,1384.36957678,1380.06376123,1264.0448045,1234.94478379,1229.29513939,1211.72444676,1233.43773096,1225.94634645,1230.723957,1237.08116637,1240.80832322,1240.97114186,1239.03900484,1284.61014877,1376.50536986,1335.85100319,1306.7951141,1310.61421202,1313.23339974,1589.72468022,1308.64232315,1349.56164181,1436.42676762,1437.19472574,1437.04182744,1444.09334231,1451.14090997,1459.07449958,1441.82901671,1433.05944969,1440.50813024,1433.57889913,1429.69352137,1388.76264747,1415.18110448,1296.92282912,1312.63891787,1324.12978022,1323.27683689,1323.63259773,1317.64058711,1321.30544196,1322.08050495,1333.83595527,1319.98486284,1322.5660459,1326.1957005,1340.72903052,1348.75908412,1329.65293999,1320.77210104,1327.04623036,1316.11686802,1337.68561317,1322.63096511,1316.94664622,1325.19155977,1321.63982623,1331.69975677,1401.04362381,1451.22796634,1447.52458809,1447.92768292,1435.01876725,1403.47455162,1365.8405731,1364.47540946,1382.85646065,1396.10868696,1400.26717039,1374.84874018,1377.38365093,1458.15925098,1517.75673687,1527.29117179,1520.68639153,1520.06411655,1517.46319186,1518.01639946,1521.99181722,1539.93004727,1428.81560541,1507.31029851,1509.14927289,1500.07776239,1502.50659647,1498.35194354,1501.50056196,1504.92608285,1493.98376338,1501.16215364,1498.95507777,1441.07291997,1260.26816612,1178.65026678,1200.91257562,1313.28164252,1349.3797309,1354.86841693,1350.31761625,1351.56776315,1357.5037897,1349.92620054,1363.31005578,1355.73050569,1355.63120482,1359.48963968,1350.41379651,1390.8234566,1336.75550519,1487.59234266,1491.72431846,1489.40352151,1486.81409867,1502.45161666,1485.33489538,1498.11824785,1490.02329115,1490.50769554,1492.0315521,1513.04979179,1490.14435257,1498.66988545,1396.369713,1257.39311729,1258.08524592,1189.43829894])

peaks, props = signal.find_peaks(data, width=(None, 1), wlen=2, prominence=0, rel_height=0.3)

plt.bar(range(0, len(data)), data, label='data')
plt.plot(peaks, data[peaks], "x", color='r')
plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.state('zoomed')
plt.show()
showPlot(np.array(data))
```

I guess I need somehow specify `prominence`, but I don't know how to figure out the required value. I have some other data sets and fixed value might not be appropriate for them, thus this must be evaluated from data.
Would appreciate any help or piece of advice.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you play with the height parameter. According to your figure the peaks are easy to detect. You could use the most frequent value as offset for the height parameter, but I think you should play with those values. After you find the desired peaks, you can simply do a left and right search so that you calculate the average and replace it instead of the peak.

Answer (score 0):

One way to potentially do this is to choose peak widths such that those under a certain value are no longer detected as peaks and instead replaced with Median like Niels has suggested above.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).